Is there any undefined behavior in this code?
Is there any undefined behavior found here? An attempt is made to read a variable that has not been initialized.
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int *a)
{
    *a = 1;
}

int main()
{
    int val;
    foo(&val);
    return 0;
}


Where exactly is the variable read?

Sorry, write :) I'm confused here. Are there any problems with *a?

It's *a =, it's assignment.

No, there is no problem with that.

@bekici Why do you think there is a problem with this code?

I do not find problem. Just that foo may never be called by a super-optimizing ideal compiler, so a sort of undefined, but it doesn't matter the rest of the flow.

An optimizing compiler might eliminate foo() and the call to it because it has no effect because val in main() is unused after it is assigned the value by foo().  If foo() was defined as a static function, it would be eliminated by an optimizer.  But the code is valid without undefined behaviour.

Does this answer your question? Is using the address of an uninitialized variable UB?


Is there any undefined behavior in this code?

No.

An attempt is made to read a variable that has not been initialized.

There is no such attempt in the presented code. The code gets an address of the variable and then dereferences that address and writes a value to there. No attempt to read the variable val.

There is an attempt to read a. However, as a parameter, it is always initialized, so the compiler does not issue the warning for reading it.
